# canOpenUrl and tel://

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm having trouble understanding how this method works.

From the documentation, it specifies:

> canOpenURL: Returns whether an
>   application can open a given URL
>   resource.
>
> `- (BOOL)canOpenURL:(NSURL *)url`
>
> Parameters url A URL object that
>   identifies a given resource. The URL’s
>   scheme—possibly a custom
>   scheme—identifies which application
>   can handle the URL.
>
> Return Value NO if no application is
>   available that will accept the URL;
>   otherwise, returns YES.
>
> Discussion This method guarantees that
>   that if openURL: is called, another
>   application will be launched to handle
>   it. It does not guarantee that the
>   full URL is valid.
>
> Availability Available in iPhone OS
>   3.0 and later. Declared In UIApplication.h

Specifically, if it:

**guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another application will be launched to handle it.**

Then for example, if I pass in `tel://HELLOWORLD`, it returns `YES`, and when I'm attempting to `openUrl`, the phone application is not calling it. Nothing happens, so I'm assuming the full url is not valid when attempting to dial the number.

I understand that it does not validate the full URL, but by design, why is it not showing me an error or something if I am unable to dial the number?

Basically what I'm wondering is: what is it **exactly** validating?

I'm not convinced that it just checks for the handler type and the apps that support that specific handler (`tel://` in this case will not work for iPod Touch for example.).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Validation is not the purpose of this function. It is only checking whether there is an application registered for this url *scheme*.

E.g. on the iPod touch or iPad, there is no phone app, and thus `canOpenURL` will return `NO` for `tel:` urls.

Or if you ask it for an url with the `foo:` scheme, it will return true if the user device has any App installed that claims to handle this scheme.

It can't possible validate the url, because it doesn't know anything about the `foo` scheme or whatever scheme the next app developer comes up with. And you won't want to load the App to validate the url at this point, either.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a):

> **Discussion**
>
> This method guarantees that
>   that if `openURL:` is called, another
>   application will be launched to handle
>   it. **It does not guarantee that the
>   full URL is valid.**

Comment: I know that, I thought I made that clear already in the question.

Comment: It really is simply passing the URL to the tel: handler.

Comment: In fact it is not. If it did no validation whatsoever at least for the critical schemes such as tel: it wouldn't do anything when you send a tel:*100 for example. It should return NO to these numbers, or call the phone app and error out...